# What is the best way to reheat leftover grilled fish?

Tags: fish, culinary-uses, reheating

I have rarely (if ever) looked forward to eating leftover grilled fish.  What is the best technique to reheat the fish so that it has the best flavor and texture?

I understand that some of the quality is going to be simply lost.  If you have a certain technique for a specific type of fish, let me in on that as well.

Is it a lost cause?

Comment: Fish tacos FTW - big thanks to mfg for the reheating technique, and to daniel for the fish taco suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place on non-stick sprayed foil; broil for ~4 minutes in oven with some source of moisture or a glaze over top (ie, you might take salmon and add a soy/mustard glaze) to protect hydration levels.

Comment: ~5 minutes in my oven on broil - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 11):

If what you want is a piece of fish with the same texture and juiciness as fresh-off-the-grill, yes it is a lost cause.

My preferred method for reheating leftover fish is to break it up and use it in another application. Bouilliabaisse is excellent for leftover bits, any fish stew really. Also fish tacos.

Simply break up the fish and add to the stew in the last few minutes (to prevent overcooking), or toss briefly in a pan.

Comment: Two words: fish tacos.  I tried that suggestion last night, as well as the lemon/cream/dill pasta suggestion from user2951.  Both were good - tacos win.  Reheated in the oven on broil for about 5 minutes.  For the record: I used corn torillas, spinach, and this sauce: http://soupaddict.wordpress.com/2009/06/06/wickedly-good-fish-taco-sauce/ - Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on type of the fish you have there..

Option 1. best with Salmon

It's easy for salmon. With Salmon, the asian way is to put the left over on a hot pan and lightly pan fire it. Cook it with some ginger and shallots. Add a mixture of soy sauce, salt, sugar and oyster sauce. It's a pretty dish with rice.

Option 2.

Put them in the oven for 15 mins and it retains the texture pretty well..

Option 3.

Cook left over with cream, lemon juice & dill. Mix them with pasta

Comment: I cannot wait to try option 1 - I didn't have leftover salmon this time around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking on a plate, cover with tin foil and place over a saucepan  of simmering water.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a steamer, i would go that route. Not long though just enough to warm it up.

Answer (score -2):

Try Steaming it! Good luck ! or
Fish Tacos with black beans, cheese, cilantro and salsa

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Others have already suggested steaming and fish tacos; your answers will probably be better received if you offer up something new.